devcontainer error mount config is invalid
I am building golang project with devcontainer, it run good when using .devcontainer.json file until when I want to add some container as a service using docker-compose. It always complaining about  invalid volume specification
here is the error log
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.107Z] Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/workspaces:workspaces:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'workspaces' mount path must be absolute
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.112Z] Stop (437 ms): Run: docker compose --project-name simple-go_devcontainer -f /workspaces/simple-go/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/devcontainercli-root/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1725193221673-458badc5-7cd5-4634-b1f0-b167e58fda51.yml up -d
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.121Z] Error: Command failed: docker compose --project-name simple-go_devcontainer -f /workspaces/simple-go/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/devcontainercli-root/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1725193221673-458badc5-7cd5-4634-b1f0-b167e58fda51.yml up -d
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.121Z]     at QtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:430:3355)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.121Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.122Z]     at async utA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:410:3506)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.122Z]     at async KtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:3944)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.122Z]     at async eB (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:4886)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.122Z]     at async hrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:663:200)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.122Z]     at async lrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:662:13452)
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.149Z] Stop (2037 ms): Run in container: node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-51cb8c0d-0dac-41b5-9023-b4db71e73ffd1725193213255 --workspace-folder /workspaces/simple-go --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label vsch.local.repository=https://github.com/uluumbch/simple-go --id-label vsch.local.repository.volume=simple-go-d866b8dca06eaafd520628a43e9f64e371ad9dbb37161e6f719a4638c7545551 --id-label vsch.local.repository.folder=simple-go --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/workspaces/simple-go/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /workspaces/simple-go/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --override-config /tmp/devcontainer-63ba7ad3-18af-4baf-9c50-6366c3c0c624.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --build-no-cache --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=simple-go-d866b8dca06eaafd520628a43e9f64e371ad9dbb37161e6f719a4638c7545551,target=/workspaces,external=true --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default off --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[2024-09-01T12:20:22.150Z] Exit code 1

my .devcontainer.json:
{
    "name": "Go",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "devcontainer",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}"
}

and this is my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3'
services:
  devcontainer:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/go:1-1.22-bookworm
    volumes:
      - ../..:workspaces
    command: sleep infinity

I could'nt figure out what should I pass to volumes, i have tried with other configuration like .:workspaces and ..:workspaces but still have the same error

silly mistake, it all work now using ..:/workspaces turns out it just need an absoule path which is add slash in front of it
Also for note, the .. is indicating our source code, because my docker-compose.yml file is inside  .devcontainer folder so i should up of 1 folder to get all my source code
